# Updating Strong Params - Stripe and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, strong-parameters

I'm pretty close to implementing stripe on my web app using Rails 4, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in PaymentsController#create
```

The model calls out an issue at this line in my Payments Controller:

```
 params[:payment][:stripe_token] = charge.id
      @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @payment.save
```

I figured the issue had to do with strong parameters so I tried adding the following to the bottom of my Payments Controller and I got nothing.

```
def payment_params
  params.require(:payment).permit(:payment, :stripe_token)
end
```

Thoughts on how to fix this. I was using the following tutorial to implement stripe payments, and it seems to work except for the error when I submit the form as my stripe test page shows the charges.

Website link: [synaptian](http://www.synaptian.com/blog/posts/stripe-payments-in-rails)

Github of app: [stripe_example](https://github.com/wholcomb/stripe_example)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you write the method description **payment_params** before the line causing issue in Payments Controller, like: payment_params then params[:payment][:stripe_token] = charge.id ...

Comment: I added it before as you suggested by am still getting the same error when I use                                                                             params.require(:payment).permit(:payment, :stripe_token)
      params[:payment][:stripe_token] = charge.id
      @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])

Comment: While you are defining you parameters in "payment_params" then you should use payment_params[:stripe_token]. it will access automatically your field by this method. and make this private.

Comment: write like this: @payment = Payment.new(params)

Comment: The following code is still generating an error. Still not sure what I am doing wrong                        params.require(:payment).permit(:payment, :stripe_token) 
      params[:payment][:stripe_token] = charge.id
      @payment = Payment.new(params)

Comment: write like this params[:payment][:stripe_token] = charge.id before  params.require(:payment).permit(:payment, :stripe_token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

```
payment_params[:stripe_token] = charge.id
  @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @payment.save
```

And you will have this method private in controller

```
private
 def payment_params
   params.require(:payment).permit(:payment, :stripe_token)
 end
```

Please refers rails 4 strong parameter tutorial if you are not aware of it. you can do it with simple. dont worry.

> http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html